# Anime or manga with a white-haired main character who goes to demon school

Tags: story-identification, anime, manga

I read or watched it about a year ago or half and only remember the beginning. The main character has white hair and goes to a demon school. An angel has snuck in to the school but gives her self away by his cooking muffins or some type of dessert. She then wants to cut his hand so she could make that type of dessert in heaven.

The demon king or whatever he is called made the devils go to school because the angels kept on winning questions from God or something like that.

Comment: Hi, Christine! See [our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) for improving story ID questions, and [our guide specifically for manga and anime questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/102999) to make your question better. Thanks, and I hope we find this for you ;-)

Comment: Can you add more details to the characters. How do the demons look? The MC is a demon or human? What other details do you recall, what possible website or place did you read it from?

Answer (score 1):

It's called "Demons can't be pretty". You can read it on [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/dcbp/info):

> Satan is a first year student at Demon High, but he looks too pretty for a demon with his blue eyes and shiny white hair. Can Satan overcome his physical appearance to become a true demon or are we asking the wrong question?

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches?